# How to unit test Grails command objects using @Validateable and @BindUsing

Tags: validation, unit-testing, grails, data-binding, command

I'm new to Grails and would like to unit test a command class that uses `@Validateable` and `@BindUsing`. As usual, the Grails doc has zero information on it. Any suggestions?

While I'm at it, how do I test the corresponding controller?

```
@Validateable
@ToString
class SearchMovieRipCommand {

    MovieRipSearchService movieRipSearchService

    @BindUsing({
        obj, source -> source['fieldName']?.trim()
    })
    String fieldName

    // more fields, omitted for brevity

    Collection<MovieRip> search() {
        log.debug("fieldName: ${fieldName}, fieldValue: ${fieldValue}, max: ${max}.")

        movieRipSearchService.search(fieldName, fieldValue, max)
    }
}

class MovieRipController {

    def show(final SearchMovieRipCommand cmd) {
        respond(cmd.search())
    }
}
```

Comment: Look for [Testing Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers).

Comment: @dmahapatro Sorry but I already did look at that part of the doc before asking the question. My command object uses a service. I want to mock that out and define the mocked method behavior. I'm guessing I can use `@ServiceUnitTestMixin` but not sure how to define method behavior with that.
Grails documentation has a tendency to state the most obvious. Their Javadoc stops just short of pathetic.

Comment: I changed the command to use a getter instead of field access. `getMovieRipSearchService().search`. Then I wrote the following test but it fails with no invocation error.
    @TestFor(MovieRipController)
        class MovieRipControllerSpec extends Specification {
     @Shared MovieRipSearchService mockService = Mock()

            def setupSpec() {
             SearchMovieRipCommand.metaClass.getMovieRipSearchService = { ->
      mockService
     }
    }
    void "test ..."() {
     // omitted

     then:
     1 * mockService.search('fieldNameWithTrailingSpace', '', 100)
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, this is what I've working using a mix of meta programming, mocks and what little is offered in the Grails documentation. This solution only works if the command accesses the service property and not field (i.e. using a getter, not field name), which's not a bad compromise anyway.

Almost every post I saw online with people having problems complains about the lack of good documentation. Grails rapid development will remain a false promise if people have to spend hours, if not days, figuring out how to unit test their code. Not to mention, it also helps to fix bugs sooner (couple I saw are open for years).

Hope my experience will help others.

```
@TestFor(MovieRipController)
class MovieRipControllerSpec extends Specification {

    /* For unknown reason, Spock mock doesn't work; throws NPE when defining interactions in test methods */
    @Shared def mockSearchService = mockFor(MovieRipSearchService)

    def setupSpec() {
        SearchMovieRipCommand.metaClass.getMovieRipSearchService = { ->
            mockSearchService.createMock()
        }
    }

    def setup() {
        request.method = 'GET'
        response.format = 'json'
    }

    void 'test that trailing space in the field name is trimmed during search command data binding'() {
        setup:
        params.fieldName = 'fieldNameWithTrailingSpace '
        params.fieldValue = null
        params.max = 101

        mockSearchService.demand.search { fieldName, fieldValue, max -> 
            assert fieldName == 'fieldNameWithTrailingSpace'
            assert fieldValue == ''
            assert max == 100

            [terminator2MovieRipLite()] as List
        }

        when:
        controller.show()

        then:
        mockSearchService.verify()

        response.status == 200
        response.json.size() == 1

        response.json[0].title == 'Terminator 2 Judgment Day'
    }
}
```